# Displaying fetched html tags in jsondata correctly with jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I'm at a loss here, as I'm new to using jquery/json. I've successfully extracted the data from my database into a json-format, but then the displaying on the page doesn't work correctly.

My question has two parts:

- Do I store the data correctly?
- How do I get it on the webpage correctly?

**Storing the data**

I've been storing flat text with HTML tags, but I've also tried the approach of `&lt;b&gt; Text &lt;/b&gt;`
Which of these is correct/best practice? (this might be irrelevant to the other problem, but if it's not.. Just wanted to include it)

**Displaying on the webpage**

Now on to the real problem. I have json-data which is being used without any problem (clicking one part of the site and changing another), but the html tags aren't being used, they're printed as text, as is.

The jquery is as follows:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    $.getJSON("jsondata.php",rightSideData);

    function rightSideData(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, d) {
            $("#changetext" + d.id).on('click', function() { //When clicked on: act
                var h1 = $('<h1 />', {text : d.title}),  //Get the content for the right side pane from the JSON
                    p  = $('<p />', {text : d.content}); //text on a new paragraph

                //Add the content to the right hand pane
                $("#rightside").html(h1.add(p));

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Here I did try the `$("#rightside").html(h1.add(p)).text();` as well, with no result. This was based on several suggestions that came up with a websearch.

The item in the body is constructed as follows:

```
//Add the right hand side div, containing more information
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id='1'"); //Grab the first article
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<div class='rightside color_red2' id='rightside'> <h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1><p />" . $row['content'] . "</div>"; //Paste data in the right side
    }
```

My question is: how do I, on clicking one of the divs that triggers a content change on the right side, correctly use html tags to format the data shown there?

I hope I explained it well enough. If you miss anything, feel free to ask of course! Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
On the request of JSONdata, here's the format I'm using with actual data. It's dummy data, straight copied from my testsite.

```
{"id":"2","title":"Some title","content":"Blue is a colour. <p>testpar</p> <br />testbr <b>test bold</b>","color":"blue"}
```

I want to rightsidepane to display the html tags correctly, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I do not see any JSON data in this question. Perhaps just describe what you want to achieve, as the above does not help at all

Comment: It's in there now. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more searching I've finally figured it out and I thought it might help future users to get the answer.

In one of the examples I saw I noticed they were calling something like this:

```
var h1 = $('<h1 />', {html : d.title}),
p  = $('<p />', {html : d.content});
```

As opposed to my

```
var h1 = $('<h1 />', {text: d.title}),
p  = $('<p />', {text: d.content});
```

**Final note**
It doesn't seem to work with using `$("#rightside").html(h1.add(p));`
When separating it like `var added = h1.add(p); $("#rightside").html(added);` it does seem to work. Not sure why..

It's just as easy as calling is as html (`{html: data}`) instead of a text type.
Hope it helps anyone else.